# Port binding for Spring RESTful Web Service

Tags: spring, web-services

I've used the [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tutorial to build a WebService for my purpose. It was quite easy, but now I'm struggeling to configure the port the WebService should be binded through. There is no `config.xml` or anything to configure in this project. Can anyone give me a hint about how to configure the WebService's port?

As these details might be helpful. I'm starting the server with the code below, containing the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` tag. The configuration is done by [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ServerStarter{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick and dirty solution you can employ the command line option arguments ([source](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html)):

```
 --server.port=9000
```

Comment: The link provides some further details like adding an `application.properties`. Thx a lot!

Comment: Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

To configure the ports you can set the server.port and management.port properties by writing the following in the "application.properties" file located under "src/main/resources":

```
server.port = 9000
management.port = 9001
```

Similarly if you need to specify the management address:

```
management.address = 127.0.0.1
```

There are more properties you can set for the server and management server. See spring-boot's documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/